# 'set font:' is deprecated: first deprecated in ios3 (Warning)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

'set font:' is deprecated: first deprecated in ios3 (Warning)

written in Viewdidload

```
[btnCancelSignin setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:Font_Ubuntu_Bold size:15.0f]];
```

i am using Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Whenever you get a message about a deprecated method, please see the docs for the deprecated method. It will almost always tell you what you should use instead. In this case, the `font` property of the `titleLabel` property.

Comment: -1 for an question that can be answered by looking at the docs for less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Objective C**

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f];
```

**Swift**

```
button.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 12.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
[btnCancelSignin.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:Font_Ubuntu_Bold size:15.0f]];
```